# Wrapper class does not save to database when set

Tags: linq, data-binding, wrapper

I have a wrapper class that is meant to get and set code from a property in one of my dbml's partial classes. The reason for the wrapper is for a specialized get, which pre-formats the value. Here's what the wrapper looks like (NOTE: this is not the actual code, but represents everything but the formatting accurately):

```
partial class Class1
{
    public string PropertyFormatted
    {
        get
        {
            var ret = Property.Substring(1);
            return ret;
        }
        set { Property = value; }
    }
}
```

This wrapper is bound using Bind() in a formview for the edit page. For some reason, the wrapper's value is set twice on update and the second time through the value is re-assigned its original value (causing the property to remain, ultimately, unchanged). However, when the wrapper is replaced with the property itself, there is no problem with saving to the database.

Any ideas what may be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dbContext should be automatically detecting changes via this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker.detectchanges(v=vs.103).aspx

You may have inadvertently disable auto detect changes or something of the like.  Try manually calling the method and see if that makes a difference.

Good luck!

Comment: The changes were actually being made, but it was happening multiple times over (somehow the second and third (??) iterations were using the previous value).